# Jenkins: "javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: smtp.gmail.com, port: 465;"

Tags: linux, email, jenkins

all on a sudden i am not able to trigger emails via Jenkins which is running in rhel 6.2 . It was working fine before. But i am able to sent mails via server.

Below is the error which i am getting..

```
ERROR: Could not connect to SMTP host: smtp.uk.ri.ad, port: 465
javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: smtp.uk.ri.ad, port: 465;
  nested exception is:
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1934)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:638)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:317)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:176)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:125)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:194)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:124)
    at hudson.tasks.MailSender.run(MailSender.java:129)
    at hudson.tasks.Mailer.perform(Mailer.java:170)
    at 
    hudson.tasks.BuildStepCompatibilityLayer.perform
    (BuildStepCompatibilityLayer.java:78)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:20)
    at 
    hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform
    (AbstractBuild.java:779)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.performAllBuildSteps
    (AbstractBuild.java:720)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.post2(Build.java:185)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.post
    (AbstractBuild.java:665)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1753)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:98)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:404)
    Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at 
    java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
    at 
    java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress
    (AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
    at 
    java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(SSLSocketImpl.java:625)
    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.createSocket(SocketFetcher.java:286)
    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.getSocket(SocketFetcher.java:205)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1900)
    ... 18 more

Finished: SUCCESS
```

Please help to fix the issue.. Thanks in advance

Comment: Please show your code, and provide the exact details of the connection.

Comment: @jww thank you.. Basically someone changed the configs of  email server in the machine itself..So when i  wrote the configuration in Jenkins it was attempting to overwrite the machine configuration and eventually timed out 
so i removed the config and it worked fine

Answer (score 0):

Someone changed the configs of email server in the machine itself.. So when i wrote the configuration in Jenkins it was attempting to overwrite the machine configuration and eventually timed out so i removed the config and it worked fine..